# Installshield Project upgrade product name , registry, install directory

Tags: installshield

I am using Installshield 2014. **I want to upgrade and rename my project name, registry, installation directory**. I have  updated these all information and generated  single Image setup file. but my installer is not upgrading successfully.

I am getting error as "**Error 1316 : can't  read files from temp folde**r".

Error desc :

My older installer product name **is x.msi**

new installer product name is **y.msi**

**but when i am upgrading x.msi to y.msi it is searching x.msi in c:\users\AppData\local\Temp\2{xxxxxxx}\x.msi.**

I have verified in above location **y.msi** file is available but installer is trying to read older **x.msi** file only.

please help me to resolve this issu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the name of your .msi file and create a minor upgrade, you may encounter a 1316 error. Either rename `y.msi` such that it matches `x.msi`, or create a major upgrade instead of a minor upgrade.

Comment: Thank you Michael.

If we are going to do major upgrade , will it uninstalls previous version automatically or  we need to perform manullay ?

I have updated product code and package code created new setup with y.msi name. When i am installing that application it is not upgrading existing application, it is installing another y.msi file in install programes.
Now x.msi and y.msi files both appearing in uninstall programes.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It sounds like you have not created a major upgrade item in the upgrades view. Once you do so and configure it correctly, the older package will be uninstalled.